# NSRegularExpression cannot find capturing group matches

Tags: ios, regex, swift, nsregularexpression, capturing-group

I'm trying to parse a string using one regular expression pattern.

Here is the pattern:

```
(\")(.+)(\")\s*(\{)
```

Here is the text to be parsed:

```
"base" {
```

I want to find these 4 capturing groups:

```
1. "
2. base
3. "
4. {
```

I am using the following code trying to capture those groups

```
class func matchesInCapturingGroups(text: String, pattern: String) -> [String] {
    var results = [String]()

    let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, count(text))
    var index = 0

    if let matches = regexp(pattern)?.matchesInString(text, options: NSMatchingOptions.ReportCompletion, range: textRange) as? [NSTextCheckingResult] {
        for match in matches {
            // this match = <NSExtendedRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x7fac3b601fd0>{0, 8}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x7fac3b70b5b0> (")(.+)(")\s*(\{) 0x1}
            results.append(self.substring(text, range: match.range))
        }
    }

    return results
}
```

Unfortunately it is able to find only one group with range `(0, 8)` which is equal to: `"base" {`. So it finds one group which is the entire string instead of 4 groups.

Is that even possible to get those groups using `NSRegularExpression`?

Comment: @stribizhev you have to escape the `\s` to `\\s` as well.

Comment: I have not done it myself, but from the documentation of NSTextCheckingResult I would have to ask: Have you tried checking `match.numberOfRanges` and `match.rangeAtIndex`?

Comment: @luk2302, Yeah I know, I copy paste it from regex101.com when I'm playing with expressions so it has not been escaped.

Comment: @Sascha Kolberg - yes I tried. result was the same.

Comment: @TomaszSzulc I wrote an answer that works... you might want to check that one out.

Comment: Yeah I am playing with that a bit right now. Will confirm if works :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31103410/convert-a-javascript-regex-to-a-swift-regex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, of course it is possible. You just have to change your current logic for finding the actual groups:

```
func matchesInCapturingGroups(text: String, pattern: String) -> [String] {
    var results = [String]()

    let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, text.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
        let matches = regex.matchesInString(text, options: NSMatchingOptions.ReportCompletion, range: textRange)

        for index in 1..<matches[0].numberOfRanges {
            results.append((text as NSString).substringWithRange(matches[0].rangeAtIndex(index)))
        }
        return results
    } catch {
        return []
    }
}

let pattern = "(\")(.+)(\")\\s*(\\{)"
print(matchesInCapturingGroups("\"base\" {", pattern: pattern))
```

You actually only get **1 match**. You have to go into that match and in there you will find the captured groups. Note that I omit the first group since the first group represents the entire match.

This will output

> [""", "base", """, "{"]

Note the escaped regex string and make sure that you are using the same one.

Comment: Thanks for this. Okay I thought I should get multiple matches but there is one match with multiple ranges. Now it is clear.

Comment: for index in 1..<matches[0].numberOfRanges
Will this cause a crash if there are no matches to the expression because it's accessing an element of an empty array?