# trying to parse a Localizable.string file for a small project in swift on MacOS

Tags: regex, swift, string, macos, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to parse a Localizable.string file for a small project in swift on MacOS.
I just want to retrieve all the keys and values inside a file to sort them into a dictionary.

To do so I used regex with the `NSRegularExpression` cocoa class.

Here is what those file look like :

```
"key 1" = "Value 1";
"key 2" = "Value 2";
"key 3" = "Value 3";
```

Here is my code that is supposed to get the keys and values from the file loaded into a `String` :

```
static func getDictionaryFormText(text: String) -> [String: String] {
    var dict: [String : String] = [:]
    let exp = "\"(.*)\"[ ]*=[ ]*\"(.*)\";"

    for line in text.components(separatedBy: "\n") {
        let match = self.matches(for: exp, in: line)
        // Following line can be uncommented when working
        //dict[match[0]] = match[1]
        print("(\(match.count)) matches = \(match)")
    }
    return dict
}

static func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let nsString = text as NSString
        let results = regex.matches(in: text, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length))
        return results.map { nsString.substring(with: $0.range) }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}
```

When running this code with the provided Localizable example here is the output :

```
(1) matches = ["\"key 1\" = \"Value 1\";"]
(1) matches = ["\"key 2\" = \"Value 2\";"]
(1) matches = ["\"key 3\" = \"Value 3\";"]
```

It sounds like the match doesn't stop after the first `"` occurence. When i try the same expression `\"(.*)\"[ ]*=[ ]*\"(.*)\";` on regex101.com the output is correct though. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Your output seems to be showing the right result. Maybe you are mis-understanding the specification of `NSRegularExpression` or `NSTextCheckingResult`. What output do you expect with your code for that input text?

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: You're right, i actually fixed this problem after posting, i was just accessing the first result because of a misunderstanding on how `NSTextCheckingResult` a conceived. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your function (from [Swift extract regex matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches/27880748#27880748) ?) matches the *entire pattern*
only. If you are interested in the particular capture groups then
you have to access them with `rangeAt()` as for example in
[Convert a JavaScript Regex to a Swift Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31103410/convert-a-javascript-regex-to-a-swift-regex/31104342#31104342) (not yet updated for Swift 3).

However there is a much simpler solution, because .strings files actually use one possible format of property lists, and
can be directly read into a dictionary. Example:

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Localizable", withExtension: "strings"),
    let stringsDict = NSDictionary(contentsOf: url) as? [String: String] {
    print(stringsDict)
}
```

Output:

```
["key 1": "Value 1", "key 2": "Value 2", "key 3": "Value 3"]
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, it's fixed. I'll post my code in case it helps other folks. I didn't know about the NSDictionary solution though, that's awesome !

Comment: Wow, that's actually awesome that is works like that. Sadly, haven't found a way to save `context` (comments above lines) using this :/

Comment: @Jakub: Yes, the comments are ignored when reading the file as a property list. I am not aware of a workaround (other than parsing the file “manually”).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested I got the original function working. I needed it for a small command-line script where the `NSDictionary(contentsOf: URL)` wasn't working.

```swift
func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let nsString = text as NSString
        guard let result = regex.firstMatch(in: text, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length)) else {
            return [] // pattern does not match the string
        }
        return (1 ..< result.numberOfRanges).map {
            nsString.substring(with: result.range(at: $0))
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}

func getParsedText(text: String) -> [(key: String, text: String)] {
    var dict: [(key: String, text: String)] = []
    let exp = "\"(.*)\"[ ]*=[ ]*\"(.*)\";"

    for line in text.components(separatedBy: "\n") {
        let match = matches(for: exp, in: line)
        if match.count == 2 {
            dict.append((key: match[0], text: match[1]))
        }
    }
    return dict
}
```

Call it using something like this.

```swift
let text = try! String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8)

let stringDict = getParsedText(text: text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Really nice solution [parsing directly to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39706418/2894790), but if someone wants to also parse the comments you can use a small library I made for this [csv2strings](https://github.com/csknns/csv2strings).

```
import libcsv2strings

let contents: StringsFile = StringsFileParser(stringsFilePath: "path/to/Localizable.strings")?.parse()
```

It parses the file to a StringsFile model

```
/// Top level model of a Apple's strings file
public struct StringsFile {
    let entries: [Translation]

    /// Model of a strings file translation item
    public struct Translation {
        let translationKey: String
        let translation: String
        let comment: String?
    }
}
```